# Where is the $PROMPT / $PS1 variable located in powerlevel10k, how to change user input colour?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I do `echo $PS1` or `echo $PROMPT` I get this:
[image]

Right now my input (when I type) is white, I'd like it to be golden. Where can I find the specified variable and how can I permanently change my input colour?

Comment: A variable is not **found** somewhere, it exists in the shell. The shell loads on startup a certain set of files in a predetermined order, which you can find when doing a `man zsh` and scroll to the section _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_, and these files can contain code to set the variable. Basically, you decided by yourself how you configure your zsh. A typical place for defining `PROMPT` is ~/.zshrc, but as you can see from the description in the man-page, you don't **have** to do it there. Since I have not configured your zsh, I don't know were you have placed the definition of this variable.

Comment: I just notice that you also tagged the question with _oh-my-zsh_. This package for sure also sets the prompt, based on the theme you are choosing. If the aim of your question is only how to set up a certain configuration for _oh-my-zsh_, I think the question is better asked at [su]. If you want to build up your own PROMPT from scratch, the question can stay here at _stackoverflow_.